# How to open a smoothbox iFrame popup, on button cick,for a dynamic url

Tags: php, mootools

We can open  a smoothbox popup from a link with static url like this

```
<a  id ="join-request" href="<?php echo $this->baseUrl() ?>/register/selected_groups/test?>TB_iframe=true" class="smoothbox">
click me
 </a>
```

But how can do it in a button click ?

Comment: How do we expect to guess what is that you want ? what is smoothbox popup ? show some code

Comment: @Adidi Smoothbox is a mootool popup.I want to open a url in a Smoothbox popup while clicking an button.How can we do that?

Comment: again - show us the full code - make jsfiddle.

Comment: @LintoPD, posted an answer to your old question. Maybe you already fixed the problem, anyway now it's answered :)

Comment: was answer useful ? although late :)

Answer (score 0):

Chek **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3NLez/)**

If the buttons get different url by php use this:

**html**

```
<button class="smoothbox" url="ONE<?php echo $this->baseUrl() ?>/register/selected_groups/test?>TB_iframe=true">Click me - one</button>
<button class="smoothbox" url='TWO<?php echo $this->baseUrl() ?>/register/selected_groups/test?>TB_iframe=true'>Click me - two</button>
```

**script**

```
window.addEvent("domready", function (e) {
    document.getElements(".smoothbox").addEvent("click", function (e) {
        $('test_result').innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML + '</br >URL is: ' + e.target.getProperty('url');
        var url = e.target.getProperty('url');
        window.open(url, '_blank'); //or smoothbox
    });
});
```

If the php always gives the same url you can echo it in the script instead of inside the buttons, like

```
var url ='<?php echo $this->baseUrl() ?>/register/selected_groups/test?>TB_iframe=true'
```